# Can I get the iOS6 IDFA from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

iOS6 introduces the IDFA "Identifier for Advertising" for iOS6 devices.

Can this ID be retrieved from Javascript running in Safari on an iOS6 device ? Or is it an app-only feature ?

Comment: Note, I will be happy with "Yes"/"No", if someone has a link to some Apple docs or other reliable source that states or concludes if this is possible or not.

Comment: Any luck with this driis so far ?

Comment: @i.jameelkhan, no, based on Googling and the answer here, I have concluded there is no supported way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can see, it's an app-only feature. It doesn't seem to be exposed in Safari.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?