# how to access IFA from browser on iOS6

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, ios6

[Here and there](http://www.businessinsider.com/ifa-apples-iphone-tracking-in-ios-6-2012-10) on the web are articles about Identifier for Advertisers (IFA), introduced on iOS6. How can it be accessed from WebApplication (i.e. from Javascript that runs in the mobile browser)?

Actually any well-working/well-formed way to track user context for ads relevance will be mostly welcomed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get the iOS6 IDFA from Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304933/can-i-get-the-ios6-idfa-from-javascript)

Comment: @Pointy the author states that he will be happy with yes/no, while my question is more about "how".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this post the Ad-ID is not accessible in the browser:

http://blog.adfonic.com/advertisers-2/ios-6-for-mobile-advertising-part-one-smarter-identification-through-ifa/

> ...
>
> Device identification on Apple devices – which are a hugely important
>   part of the mobile advertising ecosystem – is still not entirely
>   resolved. **IFA is still available only in-app**, not in the browser, so
>   the conversion tracking wars will continue.
>
> Until the transition has completely happened, conversion tracking will
>   be less elegant and effective than it could be. While this isn’t a
>   huge problem, we would like to see this issue resolved once and for
>   all. People got scared over the UDID security breach, so the less
>   complexity around identification, the better.
>
> ...