# Google Analytics iOS Campaign Tracking and URL Builder

Tags: ios, iphone, google-analytics

We want to track installs with Google Analytics for our iOS app.
What we already done:

- we have last [iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/resources) 3.10
- we enabled idfa collection like it says [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/#idfa)

[image: idfa enabled]

- Build with IDFA available in AppStore ("ready for sale" in itunes connect)
- we have a tracking link that was generated using [iOS Campaign Tracking URL Builder](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#url-builder)

[image]

Seems everything OK. But tracking link doesn't work.
For user, that was redirected from this link, ga:campaign and ga:source are empty in GA database:

[image]

And there is nothing in Google Analytics Acquisition, only direct traffic:

[image]

We are very confusing about the field Device ID Macro in URL Builder. Is it filled right? Any other ideas how to make the GA tracking work?

Comment: In what network are you using this campaign url?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

*The information below is only valid for iOS Install Tracking, Campaigns that target users that already have the app and deeplink into them are handled completely different.*

This was designed to work with mobile adNetworks. When you create this campaign for your app in an adNetwork you can work with them to know how to pass the deviceId, each network might have its own syntax, and they can work in 2 different methods (ping or redirect).

If you are planning to use this url in a social campaign of some sort, or if you are testing it out by just visiting that url it won't work. Because [a browser can't figure out the IDFA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304933/can-i-get-the-ios6-idfa-from-javascript) only an App can.

This is also the id used by Google Analytics to link an Ad click with the actual installation of the App.

Here's how it works for Google Analytics on redirect mode:

1. The user is playing candy crush and sees a banner for your app.
2. The user thinks it's a very sweet app so he clicks on it to install your app.
3. The mobile network grabs the IDFA from inside candy crush and sends the user to a google analytic redirect url that looks like this: https://click.google-analytics.com/redirect
4. Google Analytics registers that specific IDFA clicked on your banner for your AppId and stores the campaign parameters for a while associated with this.
5. The redirect takes place and the user lands straight at the AppStore for your App.
6. If everything goes according to plan, the user hopefully installs your app and launches it.
7. When he/she does so Google Analytics grabs the IDFA and start to register stats for your app, including appId.
8. Then Google Analytics notice that's the same IDFA that clicked on that link for the same appId just a few minutes ago.
9. Google Analytics assumes the click generated an install and assigns the campaign information to that user.

Ping mode is pretty much the same except that the adNetwork sends the url to analytics themselves so the user doesn't have to go through a redirect.

So as you can see it's quite a journey, but it should work fine if you:

- Confirm that iOS campaign tracking is enabled

  - On Admin > Property Settings > iOS Campaign Tracking inside Google Analytics
- Confirm the appId on your Campaign url matches the appId for your App.
- Checks with your adNetwork what you should use in the url to be replaced with the user IDFA
- [Make sure you have IDFA is being sent from Google Analytics on your app](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/#idfa) (it's not on by default)
- Use the [campaign url builder](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#url-builder) provided by Google.

And for testing you will need to do that through either a live ad or a test version of your ad, if the network provides that.

### UPDATE (2015-02-25)

Q: How can you do install  tracking for campaigns that don't go through an adNetwork? eg (social campaigns, email campaigns, ...)

A: Google Analytics doesn't have support for that. Other attribution tools might try to fingerprint the user without using the IDFA, using IP address for instance, but that's not reliable, so Google Analytics opted to use only the IDFA.

If the campaign is through email you might have other ways to fingerprint. You obviously know the user email, so you can store it in your database and give it a uniqueId. When the user clicks on your mail marketing you can go through a redirect on your systems where you register that userId as a custom dimension and send a hit to GA with campaign information using the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) through your BackEnd. 
Then when/if the user logs in your application you get the same userId and send other hits associated with it.

You have to use a uniqueId because the email itself is forbidden inside Google Analytics per TOS. You can't send it there.

This solution has other drawbacks as you will get hits for every user that clicks in your campaign in GA, but only those that actually install the APP will have future hits. So you might have inflated sessions with a single hit that never install the App. For that reason I'd recommend sending this to a secondary Google Analytics Web Property to avoid polluting your main property.

As you can see it's not a great solution, but it's the only way you can do it. I wouldn't recommend spending time with a solution like this that creates other problems and is not reliable.

Comment: But I thought, that google pass parameters to App Store, than user install app and in app google sdk get the informations from App Store app. Like it happens with google play and Android, when you track installs there. I thought so, because on WWDC14 was announce of the new functionality of itunes connect: http://www.applift.com/blog/new-era-attribution-analytics.html

Comment: Only apple can do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26113451/apple-itunes-connect-analytics-attribution-provider-and-campaign-id-value-passi

Comment: Ок, I don't mark it as a right answer, because I steel want to find a solution for attribution with GA.

Comment: I updated my answer, but this is a different question you should post separate, **How to do attribution with email camapigns?** The original question was on how to use the Campaign url builder, and that's targeted only for adNetworks.

Comment: @Eduardo: can't we just send email-id or whatever unique id in place of IDFA?

Comment: @eugene, No. The ID has to match an ID available when a user clicks on the Ad. And the only ID available there is the IDFA, since you usually don't control the App where the Ad is displayed.

Comment: If you are not using any ad network (example: if you are tracking a download button from an app to another with GAI) you can retrieve the IDFA with the standard API ithttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944504/how-to-retrieve-iphone-idfa-from-api

Comment: Eduardo could you please look at this question, i think you could help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34455631/how-to-test-google-analytics-campaign-tracking

Answer (score 1):

Is the information in Eduardos answer still up to date? As I understand it, you are saying that the IDFA can't be used to attribute campaign source if the ad/campaign is not placed within a mobile app? If for example the ad is placed on a web page, the browser can't catch the IDFA, hence no iOS install campaign attribution?

In that case, Google documentation is VERY confusing regarding this topic and I I can't see that they mention that little detail anywhere.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#ios-install

"Google Analytics offers out-of-the-box support for iOS Install Campaign Measurement for popular networks and provides the ability to generate your own custom URLs for any additional networks."

**Another related question:**
It should at least be possible to track general campaign sources (not install tracking) like described below, right?

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#general-campaigns

"After an app has been installed, it may be launched by referrals from ad campaigns, websites, or other apps. In this scenario, referring traffic sources or marketing campaigns can be attributed to user activity in subsequent sessions by setting the campaign fields on a tracker directly."

Answer (score 1):

yes, what Eduardo was saying is still true.

For iOS, Google uses IDFA to uniquesly identify a user. Therefore, any ad click that happens in an app is trackable as Google has access to IDFA. In a browser since the IDFA isn't available and as the APpStore doen'st pass a referrer to the app like in Android, it's not possible to track iOS conversions on mobile display network or mSearch.

One of the newest updates from our Google rep was: "With the new web bridge, you should be able to see Downloads for mSearch/mGDN in the next couple of weeks if you're using a supported SDK". So Google is working on it and we should be able to measure conversions even from web.

Currently available solution to track everything is to installs Firebase SDK or 3rd party SDK like Tune etc.