# iOS app install: Postback URL form Google Analytics to AdWords or AdMob

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-ads-api, postbackurl

I was reading the whole process flow (by @Eduardo) on this thread [Google Analytics iOS Campaign Tracking and URL Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408689/google-analytics-ios-campaign-tracking-and-url-builder)

If I understood correctly:

a) we can only track iOS installations (+ source / medium etc. ) in GA, and no installation / conversion data is reported in AdWords (Display only) iOS app install campaign.

b) because, GA doesn't support [Postbank URLs > AdWords / AdMob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErwrF.png) (only to other ad networks InMobi / MillenialMedia / Tabjoy etc. - wonder why?! despite both products belong to Google)

Thanks in advance for your clarification on this!

/Vibhor