# How to get active users distributed by Campaign source? Google Analytics campaign tracking ios

Tags: ios, iphone, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I need to track my ios app installs by campaign src. and i am using [google Analytics campaign measurement](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns) for that .

- i need to associate the campaign source with the [events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/events).
  so each event will have the campaign source ( referrer ) as dimension.
  that's will help me to get the active users distributed by campaign source ! How could i do that ?

in android i can get the campaign source (referrer) and store it in the device storage (like: NSUserDefaults), then i send it with every event.
but i didn't succeed to store the the campaign source (reffere) in IOS.

is it possible to get the campaign source (reffere) from google analytics ios sdk to store it in the device storage ?

**plase note**: I need to get the campaign source when the user install the applications. and not when a user (who has already the application installed) opened my app when he had tapped on a campaign banner.
so [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#general-campaigns) is not what i am looking for.

Thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns

In this you have something called utm_source , it that what you are looking for ?

Comment: @AmitHooda thank you for your respone, but i need to save the utm_source inside my app storage. How could i do it ?

Comment: @AmitHooda i need this because , i need to get the events distributed by campaign source !

Comment: you can simply use NSUserDefaults for that and then pass it to your server.

Comment: //for storing
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     
    [defaults setObject: campaignSource forKey:@"campaignSource"];

//to retrieve while sending to server
NSString * campaignSource = [defaults objectForKey:@"campaignSource"];

Comment: @AmitHooda I know How to use NsuserDefaults, but I need to get the campaign source when the user install the application. that's what i need !

Comment: [hitParams get:kGAICampaignSource] in the above link will give you campaign source ??

Comment: @AmitHooda yes that's right, but that's to get the source when the app is already installed and user opened the app by pressing on an ad link. and i need to get the campaign source one the user have installed the app.

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Comment: @JérômeBoé no i don't.

Answer (score 1):

From the sample code given from Google Developer
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns

```
if(![hitParams get:kGAICampaignSource] && [url host].length !=0) {
    // Set campaign data on the map, not the tracker.
    [hitParams set:@"referrer" forKey:kGAICampaignMedium];
    [hitParams set:[url host] forKey:kGAICampaignSource];

    // add this line to save the campaign source value
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[hitParams get:kGAICampaignSource] forKey:@"ReferralID"];

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i don't ask for this . i asked to get the campaign referrer when the user install the application. and what's your code do, is giving me the campaign source when a user opened my app as a result of tapping on a campaign banner,(not installing because he already has the application installed).