# how to use app links to pass parameter to app store to be retrieved when app is installed in ios

Tags: ios, app-store

I am new to this concept, If the user doesn’t have app on the device i'd like to send a custom url to download the app from the app store containing a parameter of the inviting user id.

when the app is installed on the device, i need to be able to receive the parameter passed to the app store, in order to identify the user . But i couldn't figure out how to do this with app links and didn't find any appropriate example.

any help would be greatly welcomed! Thanks

Comment: There is no simple way.  See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408689/google-analytics-ios-campaign-tracking-and-url-builder) for some discussion on using the IDFA with Google Analytics

Comment: @ Paulw11: i am not  using Google Analytics, is there any alternate solution

Answer (score -1):

It is possible by sharing cookies between webbrowser and In-App browser. The easiest way is to use the service of [branch.io](https://www.branch.io/use-cases/).